# UICollectionView Nib - Assertion failure

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nib

I have a Storyboard with collection view linked to my controller (datasource / delegate linked).
Appart I have a collectionViewCell XIB.

In my controller I have :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyXibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyXibName
    return cell
}
```

If I track cell's `awakeFromNib` I can see iOS triggers it. But I don't now why, on the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` I have this assertion failure :

*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:]***

If I replace `registerNib` with `registerClass` with `UICollectionViewCell.self` my error disappears.

Any idea ?
Thx !

**edit:**

After @Paulw11 advice I designed my cell inside Storyboard and no more problems. But I'm still curious about the original problem ...

Comment: Is there any more text following the assertion failure telling you what specifically failed?

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3505.17/UICollectionView.m:3589

Comment: Is there any other message starting with "terminating app..."?

Comment: No just that ... I'm getting crazy ahah

Comment: Searching similar questions suggests that you double check that the identifier inside your nib is the same as your reuse identifier but also, why don't you just create your collection view cell inside your storyboard.

Comment: I'm going to do that and see ...